# Update entity through DTO

Tags: c#, silverlight, nhibernate, data-access-layer, dto

I have got a common scenario: SL app and WCF service as data source.

I use DTOs for transferring business objects over the wire. I have an issue - Update entity. In the client form, I have a binded DTO and I send this to WCF. I want to know a nice way to update a real database entity by DTO data. In WCF, I use NHibernate for the DAL. My solution is getting the attached entity by id from the database and I copy all properties (with nested objects) from the DTO.

But I think it's not flexible or good. Can you advise me a better way?

Comment: Your current approach sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Like anything DTOs have pros & cons but when your DTOs are exactly the same as your Entities it can seem like a burden to do the property mapping manually.

Try looking at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which should help you speed up the property mapping.

Comment: Thanks. I use AutoMapper to map my db objects to DTOs. But I wonder can I use vice versa variant, cause I need proxy of nested objects instaed of int id and other... My dtos aren't the same as entities